# Cannot compile source for driver on SLES15 SP3

Tags: c++, linux, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have a similar issue to #68416356 with a driver that cannot compile on SLES15 SP3 (kernel 5.3.18-59.16. I am not a developer and I don't know C++.

See [Compiling wanpipe driver on kernel 5.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416356/compiling-wanpipe-driver-on-kernel-5-11)
Any help would be highly appreciated.

> make -C /lib/modules/5.3.18-59.16-default/build M=/tmp/code/AgentDriver modules
> make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-5.3.18-59.16-obj/x86_64/default'
> CC [M]  /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.o
> In file included from /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c:54:0:
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.h:87:5: error: unknown type name ‘make_request_fn’
> make_request_fn* original_make_request_fn;
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c: In function ‘make_request_hook’:
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c:735:5: error: called object is not a function or > function pointer
> device_info->original_make_request_fn(q, bio);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c: In function ‘set_hook’:
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c:764:65: error: ‘struct request_queue’ has no > > > member named ‘make_request_fn’; did you mean ‘nr_requests’?
> device_info->original_make_request_fn = bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn;
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> nr_requests
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c:768:25: error: ‘struct request_queue’ has no > > > member named ‘make_request_fn’; did you mean ‘nr_requests’?
> bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn = make_request_hook;
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> nr_requests
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c: In function ‘remove_hook’:
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c:776:29: error: ‘struct request_queue’ has no
> member > named ‘make_request_fn’; did you mean ‘nr_requests’?
> if (bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn == device_info->original_make_request_fn)
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> nr_requests
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c:779:29: error: ‘struct request_queue’ has no member > named ‘make_request_fn’; did you mean ‘nr_requests’?
> if (bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn != make_request_hook) {
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> nr_requests
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c:784:25: error: ‘struct request_queue’ has no
> member > named ‘make_request_fn’; did you mean ‘nr_requests’?
> bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn = device_info->original_make_request_fn;
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> nr_requests
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c: In function ‘register_listener’:
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.c:810:29: error: ‘struct request_queue’ has no
> member > named ‘make_request_fn’; did you mean ‘nr_requests’?
> if (bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn == NULL) {
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> nr_requests
> make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-5.3.18-59.16/scripts/Makefile.build:288:
> /tmp/code/AgentDriver/src/linux/KernelTracer.o] Error 1
> make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-5.3.18-59.16/Makefile:1675: *module*/tmp/code/AgentDriver] Error 2
> make[1]: *** [../../../linux-5.3.18-59.16/Makefile:179: sub-make] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-5.3.18-59.16-obj/x86_64/default'

---

Code References:

KernelTracer.h:87:5:
make_request_fn* original_make_request_fn;

KernelTracer.c:735:5:
device_info->original_make_request_fn(q, bio);

KernelTracer.h:87:5:
device_info->original_make_request_fn = bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn;

KernelTracer.c:768:25:
bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn = make_request_hook;

KernelTracer.c:776:29:
if (bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn == device_info->original_make_request_fn)

KernelTracer.c:779:29:
if (bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn != make_request_hook) {

KernelTracer.c:784:25:
bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn = device_info->original_make_request_fn;

KernelTracer.c:810:29:
if (bd->bd_disk->queue->make_request_fn == NULL) {

---

https://www.dropbox.com/s/apu7af2bvbkis8u/KernelTracer.h?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wri7njcamc39yre/KernelTracer.c?dl=0

Thanks

Comment: The Linux kernel does not have a stable internal API, which can be a problem when compiling external, "out-of-tree" kernel module sources (i.e. sources that are not distributed as part of the Linux kernel source). This means that sooner or later, external kernel module sources that have not been maintained to keep up with changes to the kernel's internal API will fail to build for future versions of the Linux kernel. By the way, the code is in the C language, not C++.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I was kinda hoping that a minor change to the source would be required for the newer kernel e.g replace all references to make_request_fn with submit_bio and comment out a line or two. Wishful thinking I suppose :)

Comment: Perhaps there is a later version of the software that will build OK for your kernel?

Comment: Sadly there isn't - last update was several kernel revisions ago..